# Progress for streaming a large archive file upon client request?

Tags: java, http, streaming, dropwizard

In my Java/Dropwizard based application, I have an endpoint which allows clients to download their data upon request. The clients call the endpoint using tools like Curl/Wget. This endpoint constructs a ZIP archive on-demand and streams it back to the client using ZipOutputStream. Internally, the endpoint knows how much data it has to process, and is able to predict the progress rather accurately. However, due to use of ZIP, it obviously can't set anything like Content-Length in the response headers. The amount of data can be large, and clients are complaining about lack of download time estimate.

```
curl <endpoint> > foo.zip

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 7466k    0 7466k    0     0  10351      0 --:--:--  0:12:18 --:--:--  8985
```

Curious if there is a way to communicate progress to the client via standard HTTP methods?

Comment: If they're using only `curl/wget`, then no. `Content-Length` is the standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should ZIP the archive before you send it. Content-Length headers are essential to any HTTP transaction that does not use a chunked transfer encoding...and if you're using Java my guess is that you aren't using a chunked transfer encoding (I admit I might be wrong).

It is impossible to update the client about the progress of the download. I know that sounds unsatisfactory, so I will explain why. Once your headers are sent and the client begins reading the HTTP message body, all data received will be considered message body. Anything you send to that client's socket will be indistinguishable from the bytes of your compressed archive. It is impossible to send anything that will be interpreted by curl or wget as metadata.

Another reason you should really send a content length is that curl and wget will not know when the message is ended (assuming again that you're not using a chunked transfer encoding). Even when you close your OutputStream, curl and wget will continue listening for more data until they time out, which can take as much as 15 seconds of inactivity.

If you just ZIP the archive before hand and send a content length everything will handle itself. Both curl and wget will automatically monitor and display progress and will stop listening to the connection when all the data has been received.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Compressing the data beforehand would certainly make providing the content length trivial, but I guess the rationale behind the current design was to make the operation have as little impact on the server as possible. In particular, it does not require large amount of temporary disk space which would be necessary to implement your suggestion.